# Avoid interpolations when reading lines via Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, string-interpolation

I'd like to use a simple Windows Batch file to do a text search and replace within many files. My problem is: I do not know how to avoid interpolating variables when reading lines from a target file that may contain special variables/characters.

For example, with a target file, test.txt, that contains these lines (including `!time!` and `^^!`):

```
bbb aaaa bbb
!time!
bbb
^^!
```

And with a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set SEARCH=a
set REPLACE=x
set FILE=test.txt

for /f "delims=" %%A in (%FILE%) DO (
  set line=%%A
  set line=!line:%SEARCH%=%REPLACE%!
  echo !line!
)
```

I get the following output:

```
bbb xxxx bbb
18:51:27.00
bbb
^
```

But I want this output (preserving `!time!` and `^^!`):

```
bbb xxxx bbb
!time!
bbb
^^!
```

Are there any tricks to avoid the interpolation, while still using a simple Windows Batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't occur during the read. It happens when you attempt to expand the value of `%%A` and delayed expansion is enabled. It's a problem because delayed expansion occurs after FOR variable expansion. The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off as needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set SEARCH=a
set REPLACE=x
set FILE=test.txt

for /f "delims=" %%A in (%FILE%) DO (
  set line=%%A
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set line=!line:%SEARCH%=%REPLACE%!
  echo !line!
  endlocal
)
```